# Insert source code listings using esami package

Tags: verbatim, esami

Is it possible to insert source code listings in test problems created using `esami` package?

I've tried using `verbatim` environment or `listings` package, but I get no output.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\nonstopmode
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[randomize,shuffle,nosolutions,twocolumns]{esami}

\def\numcompiti{2}
\date{2016/12/17}%%% THE DATE IN THE FORMAT YYYY/MM/DD
\def\Data{\longdate}%%% or \shortdate: the date in the heading

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{esame}

\whiledo{\thevers<\numcompiti}{\stepvers

\FPeval\seme{round((\thenomefile+\thevers):0)}
\randomi=\seme

\permuta
\testa
\istruzionii

\begin{test}
\begin{questions}
\esercizi{
prob1
}
\end{questions}
\end{test}

\closevers
}
\end{document}
```

and this is prob1.tex:

```
\newproblem{
\item My problem

\begin{verbatim}
This is
  my code
\end{verbatim}
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample of code - preferably a minimal example - that we can play with?

Comment: Yes, I've edited my post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the problem is the use of the verbatim environment, which is also used by the package for many purposes.
You can try to use the `cprotect` package and write, just after `\begin{document}`, `\cMakeRobust{\newproblem}`. I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, it works!
Actually, I had to switch to `alltt` environment because I needed `esami` parameters inside the source code. Your workaround works for both `verbatim` and `alltt`.